# How to get all children table data if they have the same id as the parent table

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

I have 3 child tables and their fruit_id are referencing the parent's fruit_id. If the number of child tables remain unchanged, I can use joins to get the data but the thing is the number of child tables will increase from time to time.

Is there a SQL keyword or query that can return data of all the child tables that is related to the parent table if the fruit_id they have is in the parent table too? I am using PostgreSQL as my DB.

I am hoping to get the result like this:

```
{'fruit_id': 1, 'data_child_1': 'data in child 1, 'data_child_2': 'data in child 2', ......}
```

Comment: It sounds like your DB needs to be redesigned to have a many to many table relationship in the middle, or a self referencing table with parent child built into the table structure.

Comment: There is no such thing. But if you would implement it as an *inheritance hierarchy*, you would get that behavior automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I also agree that I need to redesign my DB.  I will think again with the suggested way from you all.